# making a Link in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, redirect, hyperlink, window.location

I'm trying to make a link on a webpage to link to another website.
It works in Google chrome but in IE and FF it's not working.

When i hover the link in chrome, it shows in the left bottom cornor the correct link. When i hover it in FF and IE it shows the link of the page that i am currently on.

this is the code i have on my .apsx page

```
<div id="return">
<button>
    <p><a id="ReturnBack" runat="server" href="http://www.stuff.be">Terug naar de site</a></p>
</button>
</div>
```

i even added some javascript to force it to redirect

```
$('#return button').click(function () {
     alert("oke?");
     window.location = 'http://www.stuff.be/Pages/Home.aspx';
});
```

The alert triggers when u click the link, just to check if it works

And when in IE in the f12 screen i can use  `window.location = 'http://www.stuff.be/Pages/Home.aspx';` to redirect it. So they both work seperatly but not in combo :s

Is there anybody who can help me?? i just spend 2 days on a silly link :(

Answer (score 2):

This is probably confusing to the browser:

```
<button>
    <p><a id="ReturnBack" runat="server" href="http://www.stuff.be">Terug naar de site</a></p>
</button>
```

A button which contains a paragraph and a link?  I don't think buttons *can* contain links.  (After all, when you click on the link, are you clicking on it or on the button?)  This is probably [invalid HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button), which means browser behavior is going to be undefined and browser-specific.

Don't use a button, just use a link:

```
<p><a id="ReturnBack" runat="server" href="http://www.stuff.be">Terug naar de site</a></p>
```

You can *style* the link to look like a button if you want.  But structurally it can't be *inside* a button.

Then just change your jQuery selector:

```
$('#return a')
```

(Or, conversely, remove the link and keep the button?  It's up to you.  But it can't be both.)

Side note: This has nothing to do with ASP.NET.  What you're using here is HTML and JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You can't put a link inside a button.

Remove the button tags and script and it will work like a normal hyperlink in all browsers. You can style it to look like a button if you need that.

Alternatively, remove the `<p>` and `<a>` tag from within the button, and keep the click script...